# Android change color of shape Instance

Tags: android, rippledrawable, android-shape, android-shapedrawable

I have three buttons with same ripple shape.

when I enter activity I change color of single buttons shape.

`RippleDrawable bg = (RippleDrawable) button.getBackground();
GradientDrawable gradient = (GradientDrawable) bg.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.ripple_color);
gradient.setColor(Color.Black);`

but when I reenter activity all buttons have this new color.
How to change only this instance of shape instead of modifying shape itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the `Drawable` documentation:

> By default, all drawables instances loaded from the same resource share a common state; if you modify the state of one instance, all the other instances will receive the same modification.

So your problem is here:

> ```
> GradientDrawable gradient = (GradientDrawable) bg.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.ripple_color);
> gradient.setColor(Color.Black);
> ```

To avoid the issue mentioned in the documentation, simply call `mutate()` on the drawable before changing its state.

```
GradientDrawable gradient =
        (GradientDrawable) bg.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.ripple_color).mutate();
gradient.setColor(Color.Black);
```